# how to restore items from recycle bin sharepoint programmatically?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

Can records which are deleted from list can be restored other than administrator account? If possible how? In my current project, i have to give permissions for a group who are having "Approve" permission to restore the records which are deleted from the lists. Any suggestions?

Comment: Kindly explain your requirement may be we can suggest you an alternative approach to achieve your purpose

Comment: in my current project users who are having Approve permission should able to restore the deleted items from recycle bin..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to write some custom code to get around the security model - which if done correctly can have benefits in not granting excessive rights. Here is a code snippet to get you started:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
  using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://server/"))
  {
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
      if (web.RecycleBin.Count > 0)
      {
        web.RecycleBin[0].Restore();
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: shouldn't that "if" be a "while" ?

Comment: I would recommend an inverted cycle starting to delete from the last item in the collection to the first to recover them in the order in which they were deelted

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no supported way to access the recycle bin for all items from a site collection as a non-site collection administrator.

The Recycle Bin only displays content deleted by the user who opens the Recycle Bin. So you will only see content in "your recycle bin" when you delete something yourself, even when you are a site owner. You will not be able to see documents deleted by someone else.

When being logged in as a site collection administrator you can open the recycle bin and see deleted items from all users. You even have the selection of views:

- End user Recycle bin items

  - this will show you the contents from all users' recycle bins
- Deleted from end user recycle bin

  ---

  For programmatically restoring recycle bin items have a look at the [SPRecycleBinItem.Restore Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.sprecyclebinitem.restore.aspx). [Or this tutorial on working with the recycle bin](https://web.archive.org/web/20130508084927/http://www.sharepointkings.com/2009/07/working-with-recycle-bin-in-sharepoint.html).

Comment: is there any way programmatically using spsecurity runwithelevatedpriviliges to restore those deleted items??

Comment: Have a look at the `SPRecycleBinItem` method, I updated my answer with some additional information. You should be able to work with it with elevated privileges.